# how to convert the type of an object from "pandas.core.groupby.generic.SeriesGroupBy" to "pandas.core.series.Series"?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby, series

I have a variable of type "pandas.core.groupby.generic.SeriesGroupBy" which I got from grouping various fields of a pandas dataframe. But, I would like to convert that variable into a pandas series which is working but with a lot of errors.

Here is the code which I have tried:

```
w = data.groupby(['dt', 'b'])['w']
w = pd.Series(w)
```

When I try to run this code, it's taking a lot of time to execute and also generating a lot of errors.

I am getting a pandas Series as follows:
[image]

But, I am expecting something similar to this:
[image]

Is there any other way to group the below column of a DataFrame and store it inside a pandas Series:
[image]

Comment: try adding a 'reset_index()' after your group by, if that doesn't work, post some of your group by result

Comment: Hi @MichaelHsi, I am getting the following error when I use reset index after group by:
"AttributeError: Cannot access callable attribute 'reset_index' of 'SeriesGroupBy' objects, try using the 'apply' method"

Comment: and which results do you want me to post?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pandas groupby objects are iterable. Using list comprehension you can extract the partitioned sub-series. Try:

```
list_of_series = [s for _, s in data.groupby(['dt', 'b'])['w']]
```

`list_of_series` is a list and should contain your desired pandas series.